# transfer weather data to container view

Tags: ios, json, swift, segue

Im unable to update labels in container view. Here's how i've done it.

​
I wrote my updateWeather function in main VC and retrieved the weather data successfully. when i printed weatherJSON it shows all the received data in console.

now when i started writing updateUI function i could only update the labels on main VC.

so i used prepare segue to send data to container view and sent a string to container VC and updated "humidity" label successfully. all labels accept strings without any issues.

but i have no idea how to send weather data to container view.

i tried passing values using object weatherDataModel but nothing   happens. i even declared a new object referring to container view class and used it in updateUI function to set label values but it won't work too.

I have no idea what to pass in place of string to get weather data through to next VC.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender for: Any?)     {
    if segue.identifier == "displayFullWeatherInfo"{
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FullWeatherViewController
        destinationVC.delegate = "\(weatherDataModel.pressure)"
        ....
        ....
```

Heres my WeatherDataModel Class:

```
import Foundation

class WeatherDataModel{
    var city = ""
    var temp = 0
    var country = ""
    var humidity = 0
}
```

in my main VC i have created weatherDataModel object and here's my updateWeatherInfo code:

```
func updateWeatherInfo(json : JSON){

if let tempDefault = json["data"][0]["temp"].double{
weatherDataModel.temp = Int(tempDefault)
weatherDataModel.city = json["data"][0["city_name"].stringValue
weatherDataModel.country = json["data"][0]["country_code"].stringValue
weatherDataModel.humidity = json["data"][0]["rh"].intValue


updateWeatherUI()

}
else{
currentLocation.text = "Not Available"
}
}
```

​

Comment: How did you send `weatherDataModel ` ?

Comment: Your code in `prepare(for:sender:)` doesn't make sense. You're setting the destination view controller's delegate to be a string. A string can't be an object's delegate. See  @rbaldwin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property for your weather model object in your second VC `FullWeatherViewController`:

```
var weatherDataModel: WeatherDataModel! //your object
```

And in your first VC:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "displayFullWeatherInfo" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FullWeatherViewController
            destinationVC.weatherDataModel = weatherDataModel
    }
```

Comment: i tried this already. by doing this it only sends the initialised values stored in WeatherDataModel. the updated values obtained from updateWeather function won't pass to second view controller.

Comment: Add your data Model code, and your updateWeather function code to your original question.